# Is is better to only use margin on textual elements, rather than layout elements?

Tags: html, css

I have had to work on a project that was written by someone else, and the way they wrote the site everything is positioned using margins, both positive and negative margins.

I only ever really use margins for textual elements like `<p>` or `<h1>` tags.

Using padding to space the contents within my div building blocks.

I have come across a lot of issues when margin has been used on divs to try and control the spacing of them.

So my question is:

Is it best practice to only use margins on textual elements, and use padding on the main building blocks unless it makes more sense to use margins on that particular case?

I am interested on other peoples opinions of the margin attribute and it's uses.

Has it caused anyone else issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS `margin` attribute should be used to set gaps between boxes, not to position the text (content) inside a certain box and not to alter the positioning of a box. For each of these two activities there are specific properties: `padding` and `position` (with `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`).

Deciding which of the properties you need is fairly simple. Lets take some cases:

A. *I have 3 columns inside a parent and I want them to have some space between them.*
This will require using `margin` because you clearly need space between the elements, not inside them.

B. *Each of the columns has a border and text content, but the text content starts right from the border. What do I do?*
You apply some `padding`. Even if you don't have borders and want to position the text content, you still apply padding, and not margin!

C. *I want to make some cool futuristic layout, with boxes that aren't aligned next to each other. Some of them should even overlap!*
In this situation it's clearly not a problem of spacing, but one of positioning, so you should use the, you've guessed, `position` property. Don't apply margin to space elements one from another, but rather *position* them relative to a parent (or to their default position if using `position: relative`).

*Tip: To make it easier to decide if you need margin or padding always think about what would you do if your you had borders on all elements.*

Mandatory reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: Re reading my question I think I did not do a good enough job of explaining the problem. But this answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Margins are used to create a space between two elements whereas padding is used to space the contents of an element in relation to its edge.

Update: I have used a dash (-) to represent the space.

So here is margin...

-|Element|--|Element|-

And here is padding...

|-Element-||-Element-|

And here is margin and padding...

-|-Element-|--|-Element-|-

So the question is, what do you want to use... The answer is that it depends. If you had a visible edge to the element, either a background colour or a border, padding wouldn't create a visible gap between the element, so you would have to use margin to separate them (i.e. to stop the edges from touching).

So essentially, they do different things and you should use margin to space elements, and padding to create a gap between the edge of an element and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: no. Your main building blocks are likely to be laid out with floats, and using negative margins lets you keep a sensible source order — see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/